# Multpliying a float number with integer and removing decimal part

Tags: python, formatting

I have a float number, and an integer. I want to multiply these two, round up the result, get rid of decimal part, and format it as a string, I do:

```
import math

a = 0.2236 #float
b = 39600  #integer
c = str(int(math.ceil(a*b)))
```

Is it the most pythonic way to do this? Or is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what counts as more pythonic but as an alternative:

```
c = "%.0f" % math.ceil(a*b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to use [`format()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format) here:

```
>>> format(math.ceil(a*b), '.0f')
'8855'
```